# Append unique id when directive is used multiple times

Tags: angularjs, label, forms, uniqueidentifier

I defined a custom directive in my Angular application:

```
app.directive('foobarDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'foobar.html'
  };
});
```

This directive is used multiple times within one page to create form elements. However, only one of the instances is visible at a time.

Now the problem is, that I have labels in my form that reference input fields. Since the directive is used multiple times, the id's are no longer unique and the label's `for`-mechanism fails.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="foobar" translate="foobar"></label>

    <span class="label label-danger" ng-show="model.foobar.length > 255" translate="warn_too_long"></span>

    <textarea id="foobar" auto-height
      type="text" class="form-control"
      ng-model="model.foobar"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything I can do about this? In another post, I read that I can use `id="foobar_{{$id}}"` to append a unique id, but in my case there are different ids appended to the `label` and the `textarea`. So this is not much of a help for me.

**// Edit 1:** My label and the warning are being translated using the **angular-translate** extension. This caused each element to have a different `$id`, other that expected.

**// Edit 2:** Furthermore, I have multiple pairs of label and textfield in each directive. I finally managed to solve my problem by maintaining a per-directive id and prepending a unique prefix for each pair of label and textfield. See: https://jsfiddle.net/7pxn5cxu/14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe i'm not fully understanding your problem, but why is using the `$id` not possible as unique identifier?

---

**FINAL WORKING SOLUTION**

**VIEW**

```
<!-- application container -->
<div ng-app="app">

  <!-- directive view template -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="foobar.html">
    <p>origId: {{origId}}</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="foobar_{{origId}}" class="foobar_{{origId}}" translate="foobar"></label>
        <br />
        <span class="label label-danger foobar_{{origId}}" translate="foobarWarning"></span>
        <br />
        <textarea id="foobar_{{origId}}" auto-height type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="scope.model.foobar" placeholder="id: foobar_{{origId}}"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="bar_{{origId}}" class="bar_{{origId}}" translate="bar"></label>
        <br />
        <span class="label label-danger bar_{{origId}}" translate="barWarning"></span>
        <br />
        <textarea id="bar_{{origId}}" auto-height type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="scope.model.bar" placeholder="id: bar_{{origId}}"></textarea>
        <br />
        <strong>Model:</strong> {{scope.model}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <foobar-directive></foobar-directive>
  <br/>
  <foobar-directive></foobar-directive>

</div>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
angular
.module('app', ['pascalprecht.translate'])

.directive('foobarDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope : {},
    templateUrl: 'foobar.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('linked' , scope.$id);
      scope.origId = scope.$id;
    }
  }
});
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/7pxn5cxu/14/](http://JSFIDDLE)

---

**EDIT**

Updated using `$id` usage to a pre-generated unique ID from the directives link function. This generation of the UUID is wrapper in a re-usable service `UUIDService`.

Previous answer using the AngularJS `$id` approach can still be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/7pxn5cxu/4/)

**VIEW**

```
<!-- application container -->
<div ng-app="app">

  <!-- directive view template -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="foobar.html">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="foobar_{{::id}}">label for foobar_{{::id}}</label>
        <span class="label label-danger"></span>
        <br/>
        <textarea id="foobar_{{::id}}" auto-height type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model.foobar" placeholder="id : foobar_{{::id}}"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <strong>Model:</strong> {{model}}

      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

  <foobar-directive></foobar-directive>
  <br/>
  <foobar-directive></foobar-directive>

</div>
```

**DIRECTIVE/SERVICE**

```
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .directive('foobarDirective', foobarDirective)
  .service('UUIDService', UUIDService)

/* directive */
function foobarDirective(UUIDService) {
  var directive = {
    templateUrl: 'foobar.html',
    scope: {
      model: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.id = UUIDService.generateUUID();
    },
    restrict: 'E'
  };
  return directive;    
}

/* UUIDService */
function UUIDService() {
  return {
    generateUUID: generateUUID
  }

  function generateUUID() {
    function s4() {
      return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
        .toString(16)
        .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
      s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
  };
}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/7pxn5cxu/)

Comment: In my application, I get different ids. For example ``_170`` is appended to the label's id and ``_3`` to the textfield's id. So in my code, each DOM node gets an individual id.

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.4.7, is this behaviour different in other versions, maybe?

Comment: @user1438038 - it should not change - as seen on my example. Anyhow, I've updated the approach making use of a unique UUID (through a service). This way you'll be sure you are using the unique directive id at all team, and not rely on the AngularJs `$id`. Does this help?

Comment: I would rather like to figure out, why the ``$id`` approach does not work, and change as little code as possible, since I have tons of reusable directives that would need to be change.

Comment: My label and the span with the warning use **angular-translate** for internationalization. It seems like this leads to different ids for each element.

Comment: Well you have the 2 options, with both a working example. Try updating to the latest angular 1.x version to see if it has any difference?

Comment: Is there a possibility to create a JsFiddle / Plunkr so I can have a look? Please also try following approach on https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/7pxn5cxu/8/ see the 'TRY comment' with `scope.origId = scope.$id;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146651/discussion-between-daan-desmedt-and-user1438038).

Comment: My current setup: https://jsfiddle.net/7pxn5cxu/9/ Have used a CSS class to debug the ids. As you will see, they are all different, obviously due to the translation.

Comment: You need to isolate your directives scope by adding `scope : {},` to the directives constructor. Otherwise it will be added to the current invoked scope object and share scope acros controller & directives. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/7pxn5cxu/ for example.

Comment: Thank you, I finally managed to solve the problem. Each pair of label and textfield has a unique prefix now and I add an id that is always the same within one instance of the directive: https://jsfiddle.net/7pxn5cxu/14/

Comment: If you would like to, update your answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Allright, nice! I've appended the working answer to the answer above. The previous solution can also be usefull for others - so i'll keep that one stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use rootscope to remember the id of the directive last used and then increment it. here is a working example(***run the example and check the source, all text have different id***).

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app
  .controller('Controller', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.directiveID = 0;
  })
  .directive("testDirective", function($rootScope) {
  return {
    controller: function($scope, $rootScope) {
      if ($rootScope.directiveID == undefined) {
        $rootScope.directiveID = 0;
      } else {
        $rootScope.directiveID = $rootScope.directiveID + 1;
      }
    
    
    },
    template: '<div>All of have different div(check in the source)</div>',
    link: function(scope,elem,attr){
          scope.directiveIDS = angular.copy($rootScope.directiveID);
         elem.attr("id","dir_"+scope.directiveIDS);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <test-directive></test-directive>
    <test-directive></test-directive>
    <test-directive></test-directive>
    <test-directive></test-directive>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I need individual ids on the labels and textareas, not on the wrapping directive. See my question.